# How do I pass NS_ENUM to injectParameterWith in Typhoon

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

I know that injectParameterWith takes an id, but I'm fairly new to Objective-C and not sure of the interaction there. Here is a snippet to show my case:

```
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: AWSServiceConfiguration.class
                      configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                         definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
                         [definition useInitializer:@selector(configurationWithRegion:credentialsProvider:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                             [initializer injectParameterWith: AWSRegionUSEast1]; //compile error here
                             [initializer injectParameterWith: self.awsCredentialsProvider];
                         }];
                      }];
```

What should the correct usage be in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to box your primitive as an NSNumber, using an '@' symbol, example `@(AWSRegionUSEast1)`

So your definition should be:

```
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass: AWSServiceConfiguration.class
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) 
    {
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(configurationWithRegion:credentialsProvider:)
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) 
        {
            [initializer injectParameterWith: @(AWSRegionUSEast1)]; //Hooray, compiles!
            [initializer injectParameterWith: self.awsCredentialsProvider];
        }];
}];
```

You can find more info on injecting configuration (primitives, structs cstrings, etc) in the [User Guide here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-configuration).

Comment: Perfect! I come from the Java world where auto boxing takes care of this case most of the time. Very good to know.